# Cloud DataProc and Hbase and Java ? ZooKeeper exists failed after 4 attempts. Only with Java Client

Tags: java, hbase, apache-zookeeper, google-cloud-dataproc

I am evaluating Google Data Proc With Hbase and Java.

Getting following error when try to get connection from Hbase . By Hbase Shell I am able to create table and listing table. Getting error only with java

```
SEVERE: ZooKeeper exists failed after 4 attempts
Feb 14, 2018 3:05:44 PM org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil checkExists
WARNING: hconnection-0x499683c40x0, quorum=localhost:2181, baseZNode=/hbase 
Unable to set watcher on znode (/hbase/hbaseid)
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode 
= ConnectionLoss for /hbase/hbaseid
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:1045)
    at  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.exists(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:220)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.checkExists(ZKUtil.java:419)
    at
```

org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKClusterId.readClusterIdZNode(ZKClusterId.java:65)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.getClusterId(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:105)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.retrieveClusterId(ConnectionManager.java:905)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.(ConnectionManager.java:648)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:238)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:218)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:119)
        at com.evermore.talos.platform.datamanagement.core.database.nosql.HBaseContextInitializer.createAndSetHBaseContext(HBaseContextInitializer.java:82)
        at com.evermore.talos.platform.datamanagement.core.database.nosql.HBaseContextInitializer.initializeContext(HBaseContextInitializer.java:63)
        at com.evermore.talos.platform.datamanagement.core.DataManagementCore.initializeHBaseContext(DataManagementCore.java:117)
        at com.evermore.talos.platform.datamanagement.core.DataManagementCore.inititializeQueryProcessor(DataManagementCore.java:94)
        at com.evermore.talos.platform.datamanagement.core.DataManagementCore.start(DataManagementCore.java:64)
        at com.evermore.talos.platform.datamanagement.core.DataManagementPlatformLifeCycle.start(DataManagementPlatformLifeCycle.java:25)
        at com.evermore.talos.platform.platformcontainer.core.ComponentManager.startComponents(ComponentManager.java:34)
        at com.evermore.talos.platform.platformcontainer.core.PCManager.start(PCManager.java:39)
        at com.evermore.talos.platform.starter.PCMain.main(PCMain.java:34)

Feb 14, 2018 3:05:44 PM org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher keeperException
      SEVERE: hconnection-0x499683c40x0, quorum=localhost:2181, baseZNode=/hbase 
      Received unexpected KeeperException, re-throwing exception
      org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/hbaseid
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:1045)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.exists(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:220)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.checkExists(ZKUtil.java:419)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKClusterId.readClusterIdZNode(ZKClusterId.java:65)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.getClusterId(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:105)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.retrieveClusterId(ConnectionManager.java:905)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.(ConnectionManager.java:648)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:238)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:218)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:119)
        at com.evermore.talos.platform.datamanagement.core.database.nosql.HBaseContextInitializer.createAndSetHBaseContext(HBaseContextInitializer.java:82)
        at com.evermore.talos.platform.datamanagement.core.database.nosql.HBaseContextInitializer.initializeContext(HBaseContextInitializer.java:63)
        at com.evermore.talos.platform.datamanagement.core.DataManagementCore.initializeHBaseContext(DataManagementCore.java:117)
        at com.evermore.talos.platform.datamanagement.core.DataManagementCore.inititializeQueryProcessor(DataManagementCore.java:94)
        at com.evermore.talos.platform.datamanagement.core.DataManagementCore.start(DataManagementCore.java:64)
        at com.evermore.talos.platform.datamanagement.core.DataManagementPlatformLifeCycle.start(DataManagementPlatformLifeCycle.java:25)
        at com.evermore.talos.platform.platformcontainer.core.ComponentManager.startComponents(ComponentManager.java:34)
        at com.evermore.talos.platform.platformcontainer.core.PCManager.start(PCManager.java:39)
        at com.evermore.talos.platform.starter.PCMain.main(PCMain.java:34)

```
  Feb 14, 2018 3:05:44 PM org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry 
 getClusterId
   WARNING: Can't retrieve clusterId from Zookeeper
  org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/hbaseid
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:1045)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.exists(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:220)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.checkExists(ZKUtil.java:419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKClusterId.readClusterIdZNode(ZKClusterId.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.getClusterId(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:105)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.retrieveClusterId(ConnectionManager.java:905)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.<init>(ConnectionManager.java:648)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:218)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:119)
    at com.evermore.talos.platform.datamanagement.core.database.nosql.HBaseContextInitializer.createAndSetHBaseContext(HBaseContextInitializer.java:82)
    at com.evermore.talos.platform.datamanagement.core.database.nosql.HBaseContextInitializer.initializeContext(HBaseContextInitializer.java:63)
    at com.evermore.talos.platform.datamanagement.core.DataManagementCore.initializeHBaseContext(DataManagementCore.java:117)
    at com.evermore.talos.platform.datamanagement.core.DataManagementCore.inititializeQueryProcessor(DataManagementCore.java:94)
    at com.evermore.talos.platform.datamanagement.core.DataManagementCore.start(DataManagementCore.java:64)
    at com.evermore.talos.platform.datamanagement.core.DataManagementPlatformLifeCycle.start(DataManagementPlatformLifeCycle.java:25)
    at com.evermore.talos.platform.platformcontainer.core.ComponentManager.startComponents(ComponentManager.java:34)
```

Comment: From where your code is running, is localhost:2181 the correct connection string to ZooKeeper?

Comment: Actually My Java client  is running in one compute engine instance and Zokeeper, hadoob and hbase on other three compute engine instances. So for java client -- zokeeper is not in localhost:2181

Comment: How are you configuring your connection string? For some reason, it's attempting to connect to localhost.